# Pivot Tables in Python have different formatting comparing to Excel

Tags: excel, pandas, pivot, pivot-table, reshape

Let's say we have a dataframe that looks like this:

[image: df]

I want to use pandas pivot table to format it in this way:

[image: Pivot in Excel].

However, `df.pivot_table(index='Groupings', columns='columns', values=['value1','value2'])` gives me an output that looks like this:

[image: Pivot in Python]

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

You can use the following code to create the df

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"Groupings": ["item1", "item1", "item1", "item2", "item2", "item3", "item3"],
        "columns": ["A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "D"],
        "value1": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
        "value2": [11,22,33,44,55,66,77],}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Comment: What is wrong with the pivot? It is the same thing just the column index is inverted.

Comment: may be add ``.swaplevel(1,0, axis="columns").sort_index(axis="columns")`` to your code

Comment: @sammywemmy  It returns the following error
 AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'swaplevel'.

I think axis can only be equal to 0 or 1.

Comment: @It_is_Chris It is exactly where I am having problem with. I would like to show all of the value columns for Group A, then Group B, not all value 1 for Group A, B, C, D, and all value 2 for Group A, B, C, D.